# Struct received over COM port from Arduino has incorrect values in some but not all of its fields

Tags: c#, struct, arduino, serial-port, port

I want to send some serial values to my PC.

**Arduino with sensors (master) >> via Bluetooth >> Arduino (slave) >> via serial com port >> PC with C# app**

Serial transmission works well from master to slave, but how can I receive and convert the values received to floats on the PC side using C#?

Slave code is:

Struct definition

```
 typedef struct {
  char bt1;
  float bt2; 
  float bt3; 
  float bt4;
  float bt5;
  float bt6;
  float bt7;  
  char bt8;
  } PayloadBT;
  PayloadBT payloadBT;
```

Struct sent to pc

```
BT_writeAnything(0, payloadBT);


template <class T> long int BT_writeAnything(int ee, T& valuebt)
{
  Serial.write('/');
  Serial.write((char *) &valuebt, sizeof(valuebt));
}
```

On PC app:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

 public struct PayloadSerial
{
    public char bt1;
    public float bt2;
    public float bt3;
    public float bt4;
    public float bt5;
    public float bt6;
    public float bt7;
    public char bt8;
  }

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
    static SerialPort _serialPort;
    static char rc;


        public static  void Main()
        {
            _serialPort = new SerialPort();
            _serialPort.PortName = "COM7";//Set your board COM
            _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            _serialPort.Open();
            PayloadSerial payloadSerial;

            while (true)
            {
                someText = (byte)_serialPort.ReadChar();
                rc = someText;
                if (rc == '/')
                {
                    byte* p = (byte*)&payloadSerial;
                    int i;
                    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
                    {
                        *p++ = (byte)_serialPort.ReadChar();
                    }

                    if (payloadSerial.bt1 == '<' && payloadSerial.bt8 == '>') {

                    Console.WriteLine(payloadSerial.bt2);
                    Console.WriteLine(payloadSerial.bt3);
                    Console.WriteLine(payloadSerial.bt4);
                    Console.WriteLine(payloadSerial.bt1);
                    Console.WriteLine(payloadSerial.bt8);
                    Console.WriteLine(payloadSerial.bt5);
                    Console.WriteLine(payloadSerial.bt6);
                    Console.WriteLine(payloadSerial.bt7);
                        Thread.Sleep(10);   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I receive is : 
Error   CS0214  Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context.
If I declare as unsafe I receive strange values ended with E-39

```
4.408201E-39
5.785725E-39
7.255092E-39
# this char value is correct
W this char value is correct 
5.785725E-39
5.785725E-39
7.347765E-40
```

I am using Visual Studio as my IDE.

Comment: After you read "/" char read into an byte array and then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871/reading-a-c-c-data-structure-in-c-sharp-from-a-byte-array) method to create your struct from byte array. And if you want to continue use your current implementation you need to used [fixed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement) statement

Comment: can you please give me a more exact response ? i try to use the examples provided but i get only errors

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably stems from the fact that you use default [SerialPort.Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.encoding?view=netframework-4.8). And it is

> An Encoding object. The default is ASCIIEncoding.

That means that each byte will get its highest bit set to 0, as explained in [SerialPort encoding - how do I get 8 bit ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178655/serialport-encoding-how-do-i-get-8-bit-ascii)

The solution proposed there is to use

```
_serialPort.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
```

It would probably work, but I'd rather recommend you to use the [ReadByte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readbyte?view=netframework-4.8) method instead as it does exactly what it says

```
someText = _serialPort.ReadByte();
rc = someText;
if (rc == '/')
{
    byte* p = (byte*)&payloadSerial;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        *p++ = _serialPort.ReadByte();
```

---

There may also be (additionally)

1. an issue with [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) (though both x86 and arduino seem to be little-endian).
2. or an issue with incompatible struct [layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748995/struct-memory-layout-in-c)/padding (probably not, but still a possibility)

P.S. Also, as it has been already pointed in the comment it may be better to read all bytes into an array and create the structure from it with [Reading a C/C++ data structure in C# from a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871/reading-a-c-c-data-structure-in-c-sharp-from-a-byte-array)

Comment: can you please give me a more exact response ? i try to use the examples provided but i get only errors

Comment: @hunt333r Then you should post code you have used and the errors you receive.